# mysql select from T1 if not in T2 else replace

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So mysql PDO query I am trying to write must compare columns from two tables and output array.

1. If empty output data from table1
2. if cell has value same as table2,
       output that value as first and then all other values next.

job table:

```
table1
|jobName|Name|
|job1   |John|
|job2   |John|
|job3   |John|
|jobABC |Jack|
|jobCCC |Jack|
|jobXYZ |Jack|
```

and day table:

```
table2
|day |jobName|Name|
|day1|       |John|
|day1|jobCCC |Jack|
|day2|job2   |John|
|day2|       |Jack|
|day3|jobXYZ |Jack|
|day3|job1   |John|
```

and the output for John should be:

```
day1, job1, job2, job3
day2, job2, job1, job3
day3, job1, job2, job3
```

and the output for Jack should be:

```
day1, jobCCC, jobABC, jobXYZ
day2, jobABC, jobCCC, jobXYZ
day3, jobXYZ, jobABC, jobCCC
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite see how the jobs and days match up to your example output. Shouldn't day1 for John just have nothing since no job names on day table? What is the link between jobs/days or is it literally a row by row comparision

Comment: @Matt If there is no job on that specified day1 output is list of all jobs John is assigned to. I will output results in drop-down list. Then John specifies job that he did in day1 and that gets added to table2 on day1. On next page refresh drop-down is updated with say job3 as first in drop-down list and all other job1, job2 following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got close... anyone care to help me out?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5a510/12

```
SELECT 
  b.Day,
  COALESCE(a.Name, b.Name) AS Name, 
  COALESCE(a.JobName, b.JobName) AS JobName
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.Name = b.Name
```

### Update!

Here's the final product (I think):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5a510/53

```
SELECT 
  b.Day,
  COALESCE(a.Name, b.Name) AS Name, 
  COALESCE(a.JobName, b.JobName) AS JobName
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.Name = b.Name AND a.Name = 'Jack' 
ORDER BY   b.Day ASC, a.JobName = b.JobName DESC, a.JobName ASC
```

Comment: wooh thanks @ThePloki I think I got it by adding order:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5a510/52
now, just how to get only results for Jack?

Comment: After WHERE a.Name = b.Name add AND a.Name = 'Jack' .... so it would read .... WHERE a.Name = b.Name AND a.Name = 'Jack'